# SQL: Select last 15 records from mysql grouped rows

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT temp_table.* 
  FROM
     ( SELECT COUNT(*) as hits_count
            , date 
         FROM visits 
        GROUP 
           BY date
   ) as temp_table 
ORDER  
  BY temp_table.date ASC 
LIMIT 15
```

I insert a new record into this table each time an user access a page. I need to get those records stacked by their date. It worked untill it hit the limit of 15 days, so now it doesn't show other days, it stops on his limit(15).

To make it clearer, let say I have stored 20 days, it shows just the 1-15 day interval, but i need it to get from db the interval 5-20, and so on.

Comment: Just as a guess: sort DESC and reverse the result

Comment: It is working, but is it possible keeping the results in ascending order?

Comment: put your select into a sub select and then select from the sub select with a different order

Comment: Or reverse the array

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT temp_table.* FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) as hits_count, date FROM visits GROUP BY date
) as temp_table ORDER BY temp_table.date DESC LIMIT 15
```

Not sure about the limit part though.

Comment: It's the same as Tomas Kilian recommended. OF course it's working, but is there a way in getting the results in ascending mode?

Comment: @RaduDascalu You can apply `ORDER BY` ASC/DESC based on your requirements. Where is the problem ?